# JAVA Forma de SEGURA para aritmética de enteros

Tags: java

me gustaría saber si existe una forma standard de realizar de forma **segura** operaciones aritméticas básicas con enteros, estoy trabajando en un programa que gestiona archivos de gran volumen y me encuentro con este problema básico, la cuestión es que hasta ahora o las cantidades que había manejado o eran reducidas o usaba una librería para cantidades elevadas.

```
package javaapplication18;

public class JavaApplication18 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int cLV = 99;
        long tSize = 240038342;
        long relative = 240000614;

        int tSizeI = (int) (tSize/1024);  
        int relativeSizeI = (int) (relative/1024);
        int currentValue =  (int) (cLV * relativeSizeI * 100 / tSizeI);

        System.out.println("tSizeI: " + tSizeI);
        System.out.println("relativeSizeI: " + relativeSizeI);
        System.out.println("currentValue: " + currentValue);

    }
}
```

Supongo que el ejemplo no es muy acertado pero es tal cual donde me ha surgido la pregunta, intento realizar operaciones aritméticas básicas, forzar un resultado entero y resulta que obtengo un valor negativo. La cuestión además es que no sé si utilizar una librería ya que empeoraría el rendimiento.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bueno después de estudiar el tema:

- Controlar los **valores máximos** que puede tomar la variable (int/long), esto se puede realizar con un if y generando un registro de error.
- Tener en cuenta como siempre que la **división entre 0** puede provocar una excepción de aritmetichs, esto se puede realizar con un try catch que devuelva 0 para la variable y alternativamente generar un registro de error.
- Trabajando con enteros no es necesario preocuparse por el resultado con decimales de la operaciones, no hay problema en:

  ```
  int cLV = 99;
  int tSize = 342;
  int relativeSize = 2400;
  int currentValue =  cLV*relativeSize/tSize; // decimales sin problema
  System.out.println("currentValue: " + currentValue);
  ```

Me ha sorprendido bastante la falta de respuestas y/o el interés de este tema.

Answer (score 1):

No deberías hacer una división con tipos diferentes, en tu caso estás dividiendo un long entre un entero, java te castea el int a un long, el resultado de la operacion te lo devuelve como un long y tu estás forzandolo a ser un int, cosa que no se hace asi.

```
double res = ((double)tSize)/((double)1024);
```

Y luego ya pasas el res a entero y ya veras que funciona.

Comment: ¿Pero trabajando con double no se podría superar su rango máximo? Vuelvo a decir que el ejemplo es malo tendré que cambiarlo, pero lo que busco es una forma segura para aritmética con enteros (más allá del ejemplo, más allá de dividir entre 1024). De todas formas muchas gracias +1.

Comment: Cuidado que la aritmética de punto flotante pierde precisión (hay algunas respuestas al respecto en el sitio).

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que operas con números debes ser conciente de los límites de cada tipo:

En tu caso, al escribir

`(int) (cLV * relativeSizeI * 100 / tSizeI);`

como los tres factores de la multiplicación son de tipo `int` , la operación se hace en 32 bits (signado),  cuyo valor máximo es `2^31 - 1 ~ 2.1 10^9`  (poco más de dos mil millones). Tu multiplicación excede ese valor, por lo cual hay un overflow que Java (igual que C y la mayoría de los lenguajes) no detecta, al operar con tipos primitivos.

En tu caso, esto se solucionaría usando tipo `long` (64 bits) para las variables, o al menos forzando a que esa multiplicación se haga con `long` :

`(int) (cLV * (long)relativeSizeI * 100 / tSizeI);`

Claro que esto sólo hay que hacerlo cuando nos parezca necesario. Y por otro lado, no elimina la posibilidad de overflow si tenemos numeros muy grandes.

La unica manera de estar seguros de que no habrá un overflow con operaciones con enteros es usar [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). Pero los casos en que esto conviene no son muy frecuentes.

Otros temas que debes tener en claro es que al operar con enteros (`int` o `long`) las divisiones no exactas se redondean para abajo (por lo que `20/3`  dará `6`) y que las divisiones por cero darán exception.

Comment: ¿Dices que en el caso de operaciones con 3 elementos tipo int (¿no serían 4?) el valor máximo es dos mil millones? eso no puede ser, aclara eso. Te doy +1 por nombrar el BigInteger lo había descartado porque este tipo de programas hacerlo todo con este tipo...creo que sería mejor prepararlo todo para int o long, porque es que si no tienes que tenerlo todo en BigInteger.

Comment: El valor máximo de un entero de 32 bits signado es [2.147.483.647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647). Así que, sí, si el resultado de tu operacion (o cualquier valor intermedio) supera ese valor, tendrás overflow.

Comment: ok hablas del límite del tipo int, pensaba que hablabas de la memoria para las operaciones.